# Other Country Users Minimum cart value $50

Tags: magento-1.9

How to Set Other Country Users Minimum cart value $50 
if any one knows this help me

Comment: Share more detail

Comment: other than US, minimum cart value(amount) Should be $50 required, this is client requirement

Comment: i know all country min cart is working

Comment: please help me guys

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on store scope:

Go to System -> Configuration in Admin, then select Sales on the left and go to Minimum order amount. Select "Yes" to enable it and fill in a value and messages if you'd like.

Comment: i Know this one but i want other country minimum cart value $50